# Android DialogFragment does not get dismissed on Button OnClickListener callback

Tags: android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, buttonclick, dismiss

I have a custom `DialogFragment` as an inner `class` in my `Activity`. The custom `DialogFragment` contains 2 `Buttons`.
The first `Button` opens the `Camera` and the second one opens the `Gallery`.

Normally this `DialogFragment` is shown after an `Image` is pressed.
Until here everything is fine.

Now I want add a new functionality. When the `Activity`is opened the first time, I want to open the `Camera` automatically, that means I want to "press" the first `Button` of my `DialogFragment`.

In my `Activity` `onCreate` method I just show the `DialogFragment` and perform a click on the first `Button`. The problem is that the `DialogFragment` is not dismissed.

Here is my code:

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    Button openCameraButton;
    Button openGalleryButton;
    boolean openCameraAutomatically;

    public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(boolean openCameraAutomatically) {
        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putBoolean("open_camera", openCameraAutomatically);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        openCameraAutomatically = getArguments().getBoolean("open_camera");
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, container, false);
        getDialog().setTitle("title");

        openCameraButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.open_camera_button);
        openCameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // launch Camera Intent...
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });

        openGalleryButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.open_gallery_button);
        openGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Launch Gallery Picker Intent
                getDialog().dismiss();

            }
        });


        if(openCameraAutomatically) {
            openCameraButton.performClick();
        }

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

And here is how I call it:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
myDialogFragment.show(fm, "");
```

The line `getDialog().dismiss();` does not dismiss the `DialogFragment`, after the `Camera` callback (`onActivityResult`) the `DialogFragment` is still visible. If I press the `Button` manually (without using the method `performClick`) everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try just `dismiss()` to dismiss the dialog and the fragment instead of `getDialog().dismiss()` which just dismisses the dialog and but not the fragment.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#dismiss()

> **void dismiss ()**
>
> Dismiss the fragment and its dialog. If the fragment was added to the back stack, all back stack state up to and including this entry will be popped. Otherwise, a new transaction will be committed to remove the fragment.

**Update**:

Here is another thought. You are trying to dismiss the dialog before the view for the `DialogFragment` is fully ready. This isn't a problem once the buttons are available for you to push, i.e., the layout is complete.

Try moving the automatic dismissal later in life cycle. I think that will work for you.